# Need following output using awk command

Tags: shell, awk

I am completely new to awk and I tried to reach half of my requirement.

**Input:**

```
NAME|AGE|GENDER|QUALIFICATION
ABC|21|M|UG
XYZ|23|F|PG
PQR|20|M|UG
```

**Desired Output:**

```
1>         NAME : ABC
1>          AGE : 21
1>       GENDER : M
1>QUALIFICATION : UG
--------------------------------
2>         NAME : XYZ
2>          AGE : 23
2>         NDER : F
2>QUALIFICATION : PG
--------------------------------
3>         NAME : PQR
3>          AGE : 20
3>       GENDER : M
3>QUALIFICATION : UG
--------------------------------
```

Please note that the colon(:) in every line should be positioned based on the length of the longest column name.

I've got the below output using the command

```
awk -F "|" '{if(NR==1){ split($0, a) }else{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i]" : "$i}}' test.csv
```

**Half output:**

```
NAME : ABC
AGE : 21
GENDER : M
QUALIFICATION : UG
NAME : XYZ
AGE : 23
GENDER  : F
QUALIFICATION : PG
NAME : PQR
AGE : 20
GENDER : M
QUALIFICATION : UG
```

Comment: is it necessary to start each line with `1>`?

Comment: Yes, line number should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 awk -F'|' 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    {h[i]=$i; len=length($i); 
                     if(max<len) max=len}; next}                     
            {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
               printf "%d> %"max"s : %s\n", NR-1,h[i],$i; 
             print "-----------------------"}' file

1>          NAME : ABC                                                                                                                    
1>           AGE : 21                                                                                                                     
1>        GENDER : M                                                                                                                      
1> QUALIFICATION : UG                                                                                                                     
-----------------------                                                                                                                   
2>          NAME : XYZ                                                                                                                    
2>           AGE : 23                                                                                                                     
2>        GENDER : F                                                                                                                      
2> QUALIFICATION : PG                                                                                                                     
-----------------------                                                                                                                   
3>          NAME : PQR                                                                                                                    
3>           AGE : 20                                                                                                                     
3>        GENDER : M                                                                                                                      
3> QUALIFICATION : UG                                                                                                                     
-----------------------
```

Comment: Perfect one! Working :)

Comment: FYI you can write `printf "%d> %*s : %s\n", NR-1,max,h[i],$i` instead of creating the formatting string through concatenation with `printf "%d> %"max"s : %s\n", NR-1,h[i],$i`. Makes it a bit more efficient, easier to read and then you can specify `fmt="%d> %*s : %s\n"` in the NR==1 or BEGIN section and use `printf fmt,NR-1,h[i],$i` in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

To format the output, use `printf`:

```
$ awk -F "|" '{if(NR==1){ split($0, a) } else{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%i>%13s : %s\n",NR-1,a[i],$i; print "--------------------------------"}}' test.csv
1>         NAME : ABC
1>          AGE : 21
1>       GENDER : M
1>QUALIFICATION : UG
--------------------------------
2>         NAME : XYZ
2>          AGE : 23
2>       GENDER : F
2>QUALIFICATION : PG
--------------------------------
3>         NAME : PQR
3>          AGE : 20
3>       GENDER : M
3>QUALIFICATION : UG
--------------------------------
```

How it works:

- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%i>%13s : %s\n",NR-1,a[i],$i`

  This prints each line according to format `%i>%13s : %s\n` where `%i` formats an integer, `%13s` formats 13 spaces for right-justified string, and `%s` formats a free-form string.
- `print "--------------------------------"`

  To get the divider, we print this after each line of input.

#### Alternative Logic

An equivalent but more traditional awk approach is to use `next` instead of the if-else construct:

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==1{split($0, a);next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%i>%13s : %s\n",NR-1,a[i],$i; print "--------------------------------"}' test.csv
```

This produces the same output.

#### Variable format length

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==1{split($0, a);for(s in a)len=(length(a[s])>len?length(a[s]):len); print len;next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%i>%"len"s : %s\n",NR-1,a[i],$i; print "--------------------------------"}' test.csv
```

Changes:

- `for(s in a)len=(length(a[s])>len?length(a[s]):len)`

  This finds the length of the longest heading.
- `printf "%i>%"len"s : %s\n",NR-1,a[i],$i`

  This adjusts the format to accommodate the longest header.

Comment: 13 spaces should not be fixed. As I mentioned, it should be decided based on the length of the longest column name.

Comment: @Chandu OK.  Answer updated for variable header length.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and with detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Another ***awk*** variation:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1{ split($0,a,FS); for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) b[i]=length($i); asort(b) }
     NR>1{ c++; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%d>%"'b[4]'"s : %s\n",c,a[i],$i); 
     print "-----------------------"}' file
```

The output:

```
1>         NAME : ABC
1>          AGE : 21
1>       GENDER : M
1>QUALIFICATION : UG
-----------------------
2>         NAME : XYZ
2>          AGE : 23
2>       GENDER : F
2>QUALIFICATION : PG
-----------------------
3>         NAME : PQR
3>          AGE : 20
3>       GENDER : M
3>QUALIFICATION : UG
-----------------------
```